# app not installed on android mobile phone

Tags: installation, xamarin.android, archive

I have finished working on my Xamarin android app, thankfully, and it works well as I used to debug my app using my physical device (Huawei honor 10 lite) with android version 10. now i'm trying to archive my app to get the apk file and upload it on a server so that the user could download the app from the url. I configured my android options as shown in the images. then I uploaded my apk file to the server which said upload successful. on my phone I downloaded the apk from the url and tried to install the app but I got: app not installed. why is that? note that I rebuilt my app before archiving it. thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: `I uploaded my apk file to the server which said upload successful` Do you upload your application to Google play store? If you just upload your application to your server, Please set the Linking to none, archive your app again. Before you upload your app, you can move your .apk file install in your device directly, if .apk file could running normally.

Comment: I moved my comment to answer, please accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: sure sir, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I uploaded my apk file to the server which said upload successful

Do you upload your application to Google play store? If you just upload your application to your server, Please set the `Linking` to none, archive your app again([The linker  discards all the unused assemblies, types, and members that are not used (or referenced)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#configure-the-linker). so when you download the application from your server, your application will lack of some content).

Before you upload your app, you can move your .apk file install in your device directly, if .apk file could running normally.